# How to Remove Prev. list items from list in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listView with a custom adapter. when i request for data to server my list show the data in list items.
my problem is that when i come back and search again for the data then my list show data but also have prev. data but i just want to show new updated data.
is there any solution of my problem then please tell me.

thanks in advance

Note: my listView is On Fragment.

`public class CustomlistAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    //NetworkImageView networkImageView;
    Context con;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    //ImageLoader imageLoader ;
    Utility map;

```
// Editor for Shared preferences
Editor editor;
public  ArrayList<sProperty> property = null;

public CustomlistAdapter(Context c)
{
    map = new Utility();
    this.con = c;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(c);
    if(!property.isEmpty())
    {
        property.clear();
     }
    else{
       property = map.getSPropertyDetail();   
    }

    //Sharedpref.Init(con);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return property.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return property.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
        holder =new ViewHolder();


        holder.id=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.property_id);
        holder.space=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Property_space);
        holder.bed=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Property_bed);
        holder.type=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.property_type);           
        holder.name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Property_Name);
        holder.price=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Property_price);
        holder.propertyImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
       }
    else 
    {    
        holder =(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }  



    if(property.size() > 0)
    {     

        long number=Long.parseLong(property.get(position).tot);

        Typeface tf = Farsi.GetFarsiFont(con);
        holder.name.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.name.setText(Farsi.Convert(property.get(position).name));
        holder.space.setText(property.get(position).area);  
        holder.bed.setText(property.get(position).bed); 
        holder.price.setText(Map_Fragment.format(number)+" Tomans");    
        holder.id.setText("Property ID"+property.get(position).id);         
        holder.type.setText(property.get(position).type);       
        Picasso.with(con).load(property.get(position).url).into(holder.propertyImage);


    }
    else{
        property.clear();
    }

    return convertView;

}

class ViewHolder
{

    TextView id ,type,name;
    TextView price,bed,space;
    ImageView propertyImage;

}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

 public void setData(ArrayList<sProperty> list){
        property = list;

    }
public void clear() {
    property.clear(); 

}
```

}
`

Comment: you have to flush the adapter before loading.

Comment: you have to check that the list is clear or not

Comment: add some code so we can help

Comment: suppose this is your list is "lstcompany" so before filling the list just add this line  (!lstcompany.isEmpty()) {
                    lstcompany.clear();
                }

Comment: how to flush the adapter. #ranjit pati

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear your data in adapter

Suppose your list items `ArrayList`

```
  deviceNames = new ArrayList<String>();
  selected = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

now add a method like this in your adapter..

```
public void clearAdapter()
{
    deviceNames.clear();
    selected.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Now call `youListAdapter.clearAdapter()`from you Activity before adding new data in your list
referance [link](http://tackoverflow.com/questions/10830656/android-clear-listview-in-listadapter)

Answer (score 0):

Before Performing search first clear the list and add new items by

public void clear 
{

```
 listname.clear();
 notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

write this in adapter, and call it from your activity before setting the new data.